# Android hot to change listview into checkbox listview

Tags: android

I am still a beginner about android. I had a listview of my data that I have insert into my database. But I want to change the listview into checkbox listview so that I can check for my listview data. And here is my coding for listview of data in database.

```
public class StudentDetailActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView uGraduateNamesListView;
    private Button addNewUndergraduateButton;

        private ListAdapter uGraduateListAdapter;


    private ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo> pojoArrayList;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_detail);


        uGraduateNamesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.uGraduateListView);
        uGraduateNamesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        addNewUndergraduateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.namesListViewAddButton);
        addNewUndergraduateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo>();


        uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());

        uGraduateNamesListView.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);

    }



    public List<String> populateList(){

                List<String> uGraduateNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

                AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);


        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();


        Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(cursor);

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


            String ugName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME));
            String ugUniId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_UNI_ID));
            double ugGpa = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_GPA));

                        UndergraduateDetailsPojo ugPojoClass = new UndergraduateDetailsPojo();
            ugPojoClass.setuGraduateName(ugName);
            ugPojoClass.setuGraduateUniId(ugUniId);
            ugPojoClass.setuGraduateGpa(ugGpa);


            pojoArrayList.add(ugPojoClass);


            uGraduateNamesList.add(ugName);
        }


        sqliteDatabase.close();

        return uGraduateNamesList;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo>();
        uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());        
        uGraduateNamesListView.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo>();
        uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());        
        uGraduateNamesListView.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);    
    }


    }
}
```

And here is my layout (.xml) for the listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/uGraduateListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/namesListViewAddButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/namesListViewAddButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>
```

I hope someone can help me to solve the problem. Thank you...

Comment: I hope these links may help you [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
these two links will definitely help you.

Comment: is my link helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
```

to

```
uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, populateList());
```

and in your xml

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```